# How to change the height of a div dynamically based on another div using css?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code.

HTML:

```
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    Div2 starts <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /> Div2 ends
  </div>
  <div class="div3">
    Div3
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.div1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: auto;
}

.div2 {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #F4A460;
  float: left;
}

.div3 {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #FFFFE0;
  float: right;
}
```

I want to increase the height of `div3` dynamically.

For example, if the height of `div1` is `500px` then the height of `div3` should be `500px`. I know, I can use inherit, but the height of `div1` is `auto` so it won't help.

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/prashusuri/E4Zgj/1/

How to do this?

Comment: That's complicated using just CSS. There's a variety of methods, you can check some of them [here](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/). If you can use javascript (Or ideally, jQuery), it gets easier

Comment: So you want equal height columns?

Comment: @cimmanin yes. but u should not fix the height of div1. it should be auto.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#container-of-boxes {
    display: table;
    width: 1158px;
}
#box-1 {
    width: 578px;
}
#box-2 {
    width: 386px;
}
#box-3 {
    width: 194px;
}
#box-1, #box-2, #box-3 {
    min-height: 210px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    display: table-cell;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

- The container must have display:table
- The boxes inside container must be: display:table-cell
- Don't put floats.

Answer (score 6):

By specifying the positions we can achieve this,

```
.div1 {
  width:300px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: grey;  
  border:1px solid;
  position:relative;
  overflow:auto;
}
.div2 {
  width:150px;
  height:auto;
  background-color: #F4A460;  
  float:left;
}
.div3 {
  width:150px;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  right:0px;
  background-color: #FFFFE0;  
  float:right;
}
```

but it is not possible to achieve this using float.

Comment: Try to maintain consistency in code: you have described above `color` as `grey` and then you have used symbols to represent colors.

Comment: Although mine did work. The answer provided by @cosacu is the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can accomplish that with css. Originally javascript was designed for this.
Try this:

```
<div class="div1" id="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    Div2 starts <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    Div2 ends
  </div>
  <div class="div3" id="div3">
    Div3
  </div>
</div>
```

and javascript function:

```js
function adjustHeight() {
    document.getElementById('div3').style.height = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('div1'), "").getPropertyValue("height");
}
```

call the javascript after the div1 (or whole page) is loaded.

You can also replace *document.getElementById('div3').style.height* with code manipulating class div3 since my code only add / change style attribute of an element.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Prashanth - While it's doable with fixed heights or CSS3 with potentially sketchy support (display: table, flex-box), it's not when the heights are dynamic and you're using floats (and in all cases, you probably need some amount of JS support to make everything dynamic and/or supported across all relevant browsers). [It's why faux columns have been around for nearly a decade.](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/)

Comment: @Shauna sketchy support?  IE8+ has stable support for `display: table`, along with every other browser version released within the last 5 years.

Comment: @cimmanon - Fair enough (character limits in comments FTL), though that still leaves IE7, which many of us still have to support. Depending on the level of support required, that can still require JS.

Comment: Sorry, I was just going off the last sentence you wrote about you doubting it works with float.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to get equal height columns, without the ugly side effects that come along with absolute positioning, is to use the `display: table` properties:

```
.div1 {
  width:300px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: grey;  
  border:1px solid;
  display: table;
}

.div2, .div3 {
  display: table-cell;
}
.div2 {
  width:150px;
  height:auto;
  background-color: #F4A460;  

}
.div3 {
  width:150px;
  height:auto;
  background-color: #FFFFE0;  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E4Zgj/21/

---

Now, if your goal is to have `.div2` so that it is only as tall as it needs to be to contain its content while `.div3` is at least as tall as `.div2` but still able to expand if its content makes it taller than `.div2`, then you need to use flexbox.  Flexbox support isn't quite there yet (IE10, Opera, Chrome.  Firefox follows an old spec, but is following the current spec soon).

```
.div1 {
  width:300px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: grey;  
  border:1px solid;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.div2 {
  width:150px;
  background-color: #F4A460;
}

.div3 {
  width:150px;
  background-color: #FFFFE0;
  align-self: stretch;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E4Zgj/22/

Answer (score 1):

In this piece of code the height of left panel will gets adjusted to the height of right panel dynamically...

```
function resizeDiv() {
var rh=$('.pright').height()+'px';
$('.pleft').css('height',rh);
}
```

You can try this here
http://jsfiddle.net/SriharshaCR/7q585k1x/9/embedded/result/

Answer (score 1):

**Flex answer**

```
.div1 {
   width:300px;
   background-color: grey;  
   border:1px solid;
   overflow:auto;
   display: flex;
}
.div2 {
   width:150px;
   background-color: #F4A460;
 }
.div3 {
    width:150px;
    background-color: #FFFFE0;  
 }
```

Check the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/germangonzo/E4Zgj/575/

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Here is the Pakka codes for making the height of a division equal to another dynamically - M C Jain, Chartered Accountant -->

<script language="javascript">
function make_equal_heights()
{


if ((document.getElementById('div_A').offsetHeight) > (document.getElementById('div_B').offsetHeight) ) 
{ 
document.getElementById('div_B').style.height = (document.getElementById('div_A').offsetHeight) + "px";
} 
else 
{ 
document.getElementById('div_A').style.height = (document.getElementById('div_B').offsetHeight) + "px"
}


}
</script>

</head>

<body style="margin:50px;"  onload="make_equal_heights()"> 

<div  id="div_A"  style="height:200px; width:150px; margin-top:22px;
                        background-color:lightblue;float:left;">DIVISION A</div><br>

<div  id="div_B"  style="height:150px; width:150px; margin-left:12px;
                        background-color: blue; float:left; ">DIVISION B</div>

</body>
</html>
```