# Expand div tag based on data of another div tag which is dynamic

Tags: html, css

I'm triyng to get the div tag with id name result to be the same size of div tag data which will be dynamic. How should I approach this?

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#main
{
border:5px solid black;
float:left;
}

#result
{
border:5px solid red;
float:left;
width: 200px; 
}

#data
{
border:5px solid red;
float:left;
width: 200px; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Test</h1>

<div id="main">
<div id="result">Result:</div>
<div id="data">Dynamic Data etc...blah Dynamic Data etc...blah Dynamic Data etc...blah     Dynamic    Data etc...blah Dynamic Data etc...blah Dynamic Data etc...blah Dynamic Data etc...blah Dynamic Data etc...blah </div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [This question might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257593/how-to-change-the-height-of-a-div-dynamically-based-on-another-div-usign-css?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use a table layout for this :

**[Demo using table](http://jsfiddle.net/nBhxV/)**

```
<table id="main">
    <tr>
        <td id="result">Result:</td>
        <td id="data">Dynamic Data etc...blah Dynamic Data etc...blah Dynamic Data etc...blah     Dynamic    Data etc...blah Dynamic Data etc...blah Dynamic Data etc...blah Dynamic Data etc...blah Dynamic Data etc...blah </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Or just use the `display: table-cell` property for your `#data` and `#result` div :

**[Demo using `display: table-cell`](http://jsfiddle.net/NfK2S/)**

```
#data, #result
{
    border:5px solid red;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 200px; 
}
```